reprocessing of data based on date parameter--azure databricks notebook
We have a requirement fir a scenario to reprocess old pipelines based on date.Here are the details
Storage in ADLSGEN2
Landing zone(where the data will be stored in the same format as we get from source),Data will be loaded from sql server to ADLS gen2 using
data pieline copy activity)
Bronze layer(Data from landing zone will be copied to bronze layer by converting it to delta tables,this is done using Azure Databricks notebooks
which runs pyspark code)
Silver and gold layer(Runs databricks notebook python code)
Now our requirment is,we get data daily through files,Landing zone will have archive of that data for 7 days where as bronze layer is truncate and load everyday.
We need to build a reprocess logic where in if we pass the date as parameter it should trigger the flow and take the old files wrt date we passed and start processing from the landing zone .Could you please help me with this
tried with  the Databricks notebook triggered by ADF or the Databricks Job Scheduler, use the dbutils.fs.ls function to list files in the landing zone based on the reprocessing date and then trigger the normal flow which copies these files from landing to broze and continue with the execution of rest of the layers,but it did not work

Can you explain what did not work? did you get an error message?

You say you tried something. Can you share the code that you tried?

You can use below code in the databricks notebook to achieve your requirement.
import datetime
import time

date_time = datetime.datetime.now() # current date
week_ago = date_time - datetime.timedelta(days=7) # day-7 date
time_t=time.mktime(week_ago.timetuple()) # converted into unix timestamp
print(week_ago)
print(time_t)

l=[] # list to store the required file paths

files = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/mymount1")
for file in files:
    if file.modificationTime > time_t:  # append to the list if modification time satisfies
        l.append(file.path)
print(l)

Pass your date to this notebook from ADF pipeline and get it by using widget. The above code will give the list of all the files which are in the range of last 7 days.

You can use this list of file paths to process the files. If all of your file structure is same and want to process all data at same time, you can read all data into a single dataframe like below.
spark.read.option("header",True).csv(<above_paths_array>)

After processing these, you can continue with your flow by running your notebook from this notebook using notebook.run() method. You can also pass arguments from here.
dbutils.notebook.run("<your_notebook_name>", 60, {"argument1": "value1", "argument2": "value2", ...})

Or you can use another notebook activity in ADF pipeline after this notebook activity to call your notebook.
